# Find hyperlinked text and URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a large text in that some word is hyperlinked, I want to know all that text and it's hyperlink url suppose my text is as per below:

*[LoremIpsum.Net](http://test.com)  is a small and simple static site that provides you with a decent sized passage without having to use a [generator](http://test34434.com). The site also provides an all caps version of the text, as well as translations, and an explanation of what this famous.*

Now I want to store that hyperlinked word and it's url in array or hash table, can any one suggest me or provide me some sample code to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *text in that some word is hyperlinked* ? How is it done, i don't think text have links its the control that renders it as a link (just as you missed the link for [3] its no longer a link now)

Comment: You need the parser of the html for the `<a>`-tags.

Comment: I want to find all hyperlink text like generator and it's url.

Comment: my question is how i can parse the html for <a>,I am new in asp.net and C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See "Program that scrapes with Regex [C#]" on this page: http://www.dotnetperls.com/scraping-html

It basically works by regexing your text and collecting the matches.

Answer (score 0):

Try the [HTMLAgilityPack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack) http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack

Something like

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.Load("file.htm");
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
     HtmlAttribute att = link["href"];
   // these are your hrefs!
 }
```

You will lose your mind if you don't use a proper HTML parser.